# How do i create a branch in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to create a branch on TFS in Visual Studio Team Services.

Is this possible and if so how can i do this?

Comment: why has my question been down voted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Team Foundation Version Control, you can use the Source Explorer in Visual Studio to create a new branch and then checkin your changes (see [Branch folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files)).

If you're using Git you can use the Branches page in the Team Explorer to create a new branch (see [Create work in branches](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/branches)). For more advanced scenarios you can also use the command line.